# Prime number question?

Tags: prime-numbers

If I want to calculate all the primes, could I do this?
Let $N = \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..\}$
Then the elements in $N - NN$ are prime? Because they are the ones that aren't composite?

Comment: What is $NN$? And what is $N-NN$?

Comment: NN is the set product, and N - NN is all the elements in N which are not contained in NN.

Comment: This is what's in action  in *Eratosthenes's sieve*.

Comment: @bernard but in a very effective way! Deleting the numbers sequentially is very slow.

Comment: Who's more effective? Our old friend Ἐρατοσθένης?

Comment: It seems to me it's only theoretically faster. You first have to set up the list of all products of two numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is correct.

If $m$ is a composite, then it can be written as $n\cdot k$ for some $2\leq n,k<m$, which means that $m\in NN$.

If $m$ is a prime number, then it cannot be written as such product, so it is not in $NN$. Therefore $N-NN$ is exactly the prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes. You may struggle to compute $N-NN$, but that set would contain the primes and only the primes.

If you want to actually *calculate* prime numbers, a good way would be to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (the animation uses $n=10$). The idea is you start with a list of primes up to some number $n$, and then consider the integers up to $n^{2}$. Every composite number in this interval must have at least one prime factor at most as large as $n$, so if you eliminate all the multiples of primes up to $n$, you have all the primes up to $n^{2}$.